# Java fragmentTransaction for classes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fragmenttransaction

Ive been using FragmentTransaction in a project of mine to set the initial fragment

```
//Set the fragment initially
MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

but now im using classes and I want to set an initial xml to display on the running of a class. how would i do this. thanks

Comment: Can you please explain more?
Fragments are classes already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by class you mean Activity you can use

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
 }
```